# function to return the windows installed drive?

Tags: c++, c, windows, function, msdn

i would like to know the function which returns the drive where the windows has been installed.
for example 
   if we run a program with following code in windows which is installed in "C:\"
  temp_char = getWindowsInstalledDrive();

should return "C:\".

please point me to that function if you know. it should be a C/C++ function.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you indicate precisely why you want this? What do you want to do about junctions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GetSystemDirectory(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724373%28VS.85%29.aspx and then take the first 3 letters.

Answer (score 2):

Use [GetWindowsDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724454%28VS.85%29.aspx), and then extract the drive from the first three characters. This function is described as "legacy" in the help, but should work on all existing Windows versions.